# Do Apps using iOS Social Framework get affected by Twitter Rate Limits?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, twitter, rate-limiting

I'm making an app that utilizes Apple's Social Framework to access Twitter. I plan on eventually releasing it on the app store. I know twitter has rate limits such as 15 requests/15 mins per endpoint per user. I am also aware that twitter has 100,000 user limit for apps, however I don't know how this works with Apple Social Framework. I don't explicitly create an app on twitter's site, and don't have a client id. Since there is no application id when using Social Framework, do these limits still apply?